# Why YouTube JavaScript Player API open a different URL than the one in my code, and just play the first video of a playlist?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, youtube, youtube-javascript-api, playlist

It is my first post, I hope I respected all the rules.

I am trying to publish on a page of my website a:
shuffle / muted / autoplay youtube playlist.

I used the method AS3, with SWFObject.

Everything worked fine with the following code, but since few weeks, the player doesn't detect my playlist and just play the first video.

In the code, the URL is : 
https://www.youtube.com/v/HuIGf4IJzdM&**list=PLo**-QIlIZx6myBxEysxrWoE-f58-psKGji

But when I open the page of the page, it open the following link :
https://www.youtube.com/v/HuIGf4IJzdM&**list=o**-QIlIZx6myBxEysxrWoE-f58-psKGji

Here is the code wich, if I am not wrong, works fine precedently :

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<div id="ytapiplayer">You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("swfobject", "2.2");
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
ytplayer.playVideo();
ytplayer.setShuffle(true);
ytplayer.mute();
}
var params = {allowScriptAccess: "always" , allowFullScreen : "true"};
var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };

swfobject.embedSWF("https://www.youtube.com/v/HuIGf4IJzdM&list=PLo-QIlIZx6myBxEysxrWoE-f58-psKGji&index=0&feature=plpp_play_all?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&allowFullScreen=true&version=3&loop=1&autohide=1",
"ytapiplayer", "50%", "50%", "10", null, null, params, atts)
</script>
```

Thank you a lot if someone can help me to fin the solution to this problem !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an alternative way to make it work with an iframe.

Here is the code :

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script>

  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }

    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {

    event.target.loadPlaylist({'listType': 'playlist',
                               'list': 'PLo-QIlIZx6myBxEysxrWoE-f58-psKGji',
                               'index': '0'
                              });
      event.target.mute();
      event.target.setLoop(true);
    setTimeout( function() { 
        event.target.setShuffle(true); 
    }, 2000);
      }
</script>
```

Thank you for the help :-)

Comment: This got me so close! A pity it doesn't shuffle the first song loaded

Answer (score 0):

> ...the player doesn't detect my playlist and just play the first video.

Youtube has moved on to the newer iFrame API and that one does allow playlists.

Try this example code below by pasting it **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_youtubeiframe)** (click "**See Result**")

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe width="700" height="400"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HuIGf4IJzdM?list=PLo-QIlIZx6myBxEysxrWoE-f58-psKGji">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

See how it's within an `<iframe>` tag? Not SWF, not JS, just working with iFrame. You must add a similar tag to your website code (remove & replace your shown `script` code).

**NOTES :**

- Also notice the iFrame url begins with
  `https://www.youtube.com/embed/` this gives you the HTML5 player
  meaning it will work on mobile too. Site visitors using phones or
  tablets can watch. This is the best working option for all your site
  visitors.
- If you really want Flash in the iFrame then change beginning to
  `https://www.youtube.com/v/` this gives you the SWF player which
  means it will need the Flash Player plugin (not available on mobile).
  People using phones or tablets to visit your site **cannot** watch
  (they get a blank white box or some message like "Plugin not
  available").