# YouTube onStateChange event is suddenly not working

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, dom-events, swfobject

I had everything working fine until about two weeks ago. I haven't changed any code.

```js
function loadYtVideo(video, advert, advert_link, splash, splash_link){
   var params  = { allowScriptAccess: "always", wmode: "transparent" };
   var atts    = { id: "eda-player", wmode: "transparent" };
   var swfobject;
   adv.orig    = video;
   swfobject.embedSWF("https://www.youtube.com/v/"+adv.orig+"?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer","ytapiplayer", "719", "404", "8", null, null, params, atts);
}

function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    //It's fired
    edaplayer = document.getElementById('eda-player');
    edaplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "playerState");
}

function playerState(state) {
    //it's not fired
    console.log(state);
}
```

```html
<div class="adv-video">
   <div id="ytapiplayer">
       <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
               loadYtVideo($.getUrlVar('ytVideo'), 'eM2ja9LE0YE', 'http://wilmax.ru/', '', '');
           });
       </script>
   </div>
</div>
```

I found posts with similar problem, but solutions in those posts are not working in this case.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you move to [YouTube IFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference):

> The IFrame player API lets you embed a YouTube video player on your website and control the player using JavaScript. Unlike the [Flash](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference) and [JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) player APIs, which both involve embedding a Flash object on your web page, the IFrame API posts content to an **`<iframe>`** tag on your page. This approach provides more flexibility than the previously available APIs since it allows YouTube to serve an HTML5 player rather than a Flash player for mobile devices that do not support Flash.

[Flash API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference) and [JS API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?csw=1) has already been deprecated. I'm not sure if it still work with the current API that is why I suggest you to use Iframe API

Here are some sources that may help you:

- [JS Fiddle Demo](https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject)
- [embedding Flash](https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject)
- [Related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035124/why-youtube-javascript-player-api-open-a-different-url-than-the-one-in-my-code)

Hope this helps!